# Creating a new iPhone contact from an email in a specific address book

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have two e-mail accounts on my iPhone 4, one of which is my "work" Exchange account, and I therefore have two sets of address books ("From My Mac" and "Work").

From an e-mail, and also from the Phone's Recents list, if I select an e-mail address or phone number and then select "Create New Contact", I am not given an opportunity to select the address book that it should be added to. It *always* adds it to my work (Exchange) address book.

How do I select which address book I to create a new contact in? Alternatively (and less preferably) how can I move the contact after-the-fact from one address book to the other.

I'm not interested in solutions that involve having to sync with my mac every time, using iCloud, Google Mail or anything that I have to pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do this. However, there are some third-party apps that fill this gap. A free one that I've tested and works is [OrbiContacts](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/orbicontacts/id470885623?mt=8). The interface isn't especially pretty, but it does work.